# How to remove line sample?

Tags: interface

You can sample the pixels of an image in a line with the *Sample Line* option in *UV/Image editor > Properties Region > Sample Line*, then dragging a line across an image.

However, I can't figure out how to remove the line afterwards. (I can zoom out and sample a new line far away from the image so it is less distracting, but this can't be the right way to do it)

How to remove or hide the *sample line*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have to re-initiate it and then cancel that operation.
If you have a line you can just <kbd>LMB</kbd> on the button once to activate it then <kbd>RMB</kbd> on it again.
You can also invoke the space-function search menu and search 'Sample Color' activate it and hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> to cancel it.

[image: Sample Line]

Comment: Odd, I just tried this (both R and L MB) and it didn't work.. (I tried it during a render, but that shouldn't have anything to do with it?)

Comment: My render finished, and now it works.. and I'm reporting this as a bug ;)

Comment: Note, bug is now fixed for 2.69 release.

Answer (score 2):

Click the *Sample Line* button again, then <kbd>RMB</kbd> to cancel - and the previous line will be gone.

If you want a button to directly remove it, edit the space_image.py script like shown below:

```
class IMAGE_PT_sample_line(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'PREVIEW'
    bl_label = "Sample Line"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        sima = context.space_data
        return (sima and sima.image)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        sima = context.space_data
        hist = sima.sample_histogram

        # Add a remove button for sample line
        split = layout.split(0.9, align=True)
        split.operator("image.sample_line")
        sub = layout.row()
        sub.operator_context = 'EXEC_DEFAULT'
        split.operator("image.sample_line", icon='X', text="")

        layout.template_histogram(sima, "sample_histogram")
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.prop(hist, "mode", expand=True)
        row.prop(hist, "show_line", text="")
```

Comment: Odd, I just tried this and it didn't work.. (I was rendering, but that shouldn't have anything to do with it?)

Comment: Hm not sure, better wait for a dev to answer this question. There should really be a "remove" button IMO and it should work while rendering as well.

Comment: Should I wait to post a bug report?

Comment: I tested removing the line with your UI button while rendering, and it works.

Comment: Great :) But still, better report and add a link to the tracker.

Comment: added report: https://projects.blender.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=36981&group_id=9&atid=498